# Can not create new folders with GCS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

It is said that "Folder with entered name already exists" and We can not create new folder.

There is no folder with the same name.

**Screenshot**
[image: screenshot]

What should I do?

Comment: Did you try with another name? or is the problem  only with one name?

Comment: @JohnBalvinArias Any name cause this error as well

Comment: Try it with command line, maybe it's UI error https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/quickstart-gsutil

Comment: If you create a new bucket will the error continue?

Comment: @touyu Could you explain how you managed to overcome the error and share it as an answer for the benefit of the community? Or was this just an intermittent issue with the UI?